# How to extract elements from xml having multiple namespaces using java smooks and freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker, smooks

I'm trying an XML-XML transformation using Smooks. Running into issues when the input XML has multiple namespaces.

This is my sample input file

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <look:Trans xmlns:look="http://www.example.com">
     <Response>0</Response>
     <DGX>
       <SIGN>1</SIGN>
     </DGX> 
   </look:Trans>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And my smooks config file

```
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
 xmlns:core="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/smooks-core-1.4.xsd"
 xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd">

<params>
    <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
    <param name="default.serialization.on">false</param>
</params>

<resource-config selector="Trans">
    <resource>org.milyn.delivery.DomModelCreator</resource>
</resource-config>

<ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="Trans">
    <ftl:template>
<!--  <#ftl ns_prefixes={"look": "http://www.example.com"}> <#outputformat 'XML'> 
<Response> 
    <Code>${look\:Trans.Response} </Code>
    <Sign>${look\:Trans.DGX.SIGN} </Sign>
</Response> </#outputformat> -->
    </ftl:template>
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which XML node does Smooks choose as the template context root... if it's `soapenv:Body` then I don't see the problem in your template. Anyway, I have tried this on http://try.freemarker.org/, where the `doc` is the document node (so that's a difference to Smooks), to prove that multiple namespaces should work like that:

Template:

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"look": "http://www.example.com", "soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"}
      output_format="XML">
${doc.soapenv\:Envelope.soapenv\:Body.look\:Trans.DGX.SIGN}
```

Data-model:

```
doc=
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <look:Trans xmlns:look="http://www.example.com">
     <Response>0</Response>
     <DGX>
       <SIGN>123</SIGN>
     </DGX> 
   </look:Trans>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Result:

```
123
```

BTW, note that instead of `<#outputformat 'XML'>...</#outputformat>` you can just add `output_format='XML'` to `<#ftl ...>`. It's shorter.